# Visual Studio Code Marks Wrong Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have set up VSCode for C++ both on Win and Linux and am experiencing some issues with code markings. On Win, everything works beautifully but on Ubuntu VSCode marks standard containers as errors. I have included everything correctly and the code compiles fine, also I set the library/include search path for code correction. I included a screen shot to illustrate the situation.

[image]

Here the include Path:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you try to compile does it compile or do you get an error?  If you get an error, what do you get?

Comment: As mentioned, it compiles without an error, its simply annoying.

Comment: Addition: I even get to the definition of the keywords that are marked as errors when rightclicking -> "Go to definition"

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue with a javascript file when programming with Ember. The solution for me was to just close and re-open visual studio code, and the issue was fixed.